# Comparable custom types which can be sorted as array items without defining an additional compare function inside sort()

Tags: javascript, sorting, customization, es6-class, comparable

Languages such as Python and Java have special methods for sorting custom classes. In JavaScript, `toString()` can be overridden, but this does not work easily for numeric values.

As a workaround, I added a method called `compareTo()` to the class, although this still requires a function to call it.

```js
class NumericSortable {
    constructor(newVal) {
        this.val = newVal
    }
    compareTo(other) {
        return this.val - other.val
    }
}
const objectList = [
    new NumericSortable(3),
    new NumericSortable(1),
    new NumericSortable(20),
]
objectList.sort(
    function(a, b) { return a.compareTo(b) })
console.log(objectList)
```

Is there a way to modify the class so it can be sorted without requiring a function to be defined inside `sort()`?

Perhaps there is a good way to override `toString()` that will work for numeric values. However, solutions such as `localeCompare()` or a collator require two arguments, and they would not be passed to the overridden `toString()` method at the same time.

Comment: JavaScript's `sort()` method is not really designed to be extensible in an OO way.

Comment: The OP needs to wrap the build-in `sort` method into an own/custom implementation of `Array.prototype.sort`. But why should one do it? Just for the sake of not writing a comparing sort-callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a static method to your `NumericSortable` class, and pass that into the `sort` call. This idea can be extended to any custom class that need to define how two instances are to be compared for sorting.

```js
class NumericSortable  {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  
  static compare(a,b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
  }
}

const arr = [
  new NumericSortable(3),
  new NumericSortable(1),
  new NumericSortable(20),
];

arr.sort(NumericSortable.compare);

console.log(arr);
```

This makes things more explicit, and easier for anyone else reading the code to reason about how the array is being sorted.

Comment: This works well for my project.

Answer (score 1):

I like to make a function that returns a sort function for these cases.

```
function by(prop){
  return function(a,b){return a[prop]-b[prop];};
}
```

this let's you specify the object's to-be-sorted property at call-time, letting one generic function do a lot of heavy lifting.

```
objectList.sort(by("val"))
```

This avoids the need for a custom callback each sort, though with fat arrows that's not the burden it used to be anyway...

Comment: I could see how this would be good under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If no comparator is provided, [each time two items in the array are compared, they'll be coerced to strings](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.sort), and then those strings will be compared lexiographically to determine which object will come before the other in the sorted array. So, if you don't want to pass a comparator, adding a `toString` method to implement the desired sorting logic is the only other approach.

Unfortunately, for your situation, lexiographic comparison *alone* based on the `.val`s won't cut it; 1 will come before 20, and 20 will come before 3. If the numbers involved won't get so high as to have `e`s in their string version, you could `.padStart` the returned string so that each compared numeric string will have the same number of characters (thereby allowing lexiographic comparison to work).

```js
class NumericSortable {
    constructor(newVal) {
        this.val = newVal
    }
    // Unused now
    compareTo(other) {
        return this.val - other.val
    }
    toString() {
        return String(this.val).padStart(15, '0');
    }
}
const objectList = [
    new NumericSortable(3),
    new NumericSortable(1),
    new NumericSortable(20),
]
objectList.sort()
console.log(objectList)
```

You may wish to account for negative numbers too.

Still, this whole approach is a bit smelly. When possible, I'd prefer a comparator instead of having to fiddle with the strings to get them to compare properly.

Comment: While `padStart()` does work for the values in the example, I'd like a solution that works for a wider variety of numbers. Sadly, this seems to be difficult, so comparing is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

From my above comment ...

> *"The OP needs to wrap the build-in `sort` method into an own/custom implementation of `Array.prototype.sort`. But why should one do it? Just for the sake of not writing a comparing sort-callback?"*

Having said the above, I herby nevertheless provide an implementation of the above mentioned approach just in order to prove to the OP that it's manageable *(after all it is exactly what the OP did ask for)*, but also to show to the audience that the effort *(even though it's a one time effort)* of doing so is much greater than other already provided suggestions / solutions.

```js
class NumericSortable {
  constructor(newVal) {
    this.val = newVal;
  }
  compareTo(other) {
    return this.val - other.val;
  }
}

const objectList = [
  new NumericSortable(3),
  new NumericSortable(1),
  new NumericSortable(20),
];

objectList
  // - sorting by overwritten custom `sort` function with
  //   an already build-in `compareTo` based custom compare
  //   function and no additionally passed compare function.
  .sort();

console.log({ objectList });

objectList
  // - reverse sorting by overwritten custom `sort` function
  //   with an additionally passed compare function.
  .sort((a, b) => (-1 * a.compareTo(b)));

console.log({ objectList });

console.log(
  '... simple sort-implementation defaul-test ...\n[1,4,9,0,6,3].sort() ...',
  [1,4,9,0,6,3].sort()
);
console.log(
  '... simple sort-implementation defaul-test ...\n["foo", "biz", "baz", "bar"].sort() ...',
  ["foo", "biz", "baz", "bar"].sort()
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  (function (arrProto) {
    // save the native `sort` reference.
    const coreApiSort = arrProto.sort;

    // type detection helper.
    function isFunction(value) {
      return (
        'function' === typeof value &&
        'function' === typeof value.call &&
        'function' === typeof value.apply
      );
    }

    // different comparison helper functionality.
    function defaultCompare(a, b) {
      return (a < b && -1) || (a > b && 1) || 0;
    }
    function localeCompare(a, b) {
      return a?.localeCompare?.(b) ?? defaultCompare(a, b);
    }

    function customDefaultCompare(a, b) {
      const isCustomComparableA = isFunction(a.compareTo);
      const isCustomComparableB = isFunction(b.compareTo);

      return (isCustomComparableA && isCustomComparableB)
        ? a.compareTo(b)
        : localeCompare(a, b);
    }

    // the new `sort` functionality.
    function customSort(customCompare) {
      return coreApiSort
        // - (kind of "super") delegation to the
        //   before saved native `sort` reference ...
        .call(this, (
          // ... by using a cascade of different
          //     comparison functionality.
          isFunction(customCompare) 
            && customCompare
            || customDefaultCompare
        ));
    }
    Object
      // - overwrite the Array prototype's native `sort`
      //   method with the newly implemented custom `sort`.
      .defineProperty(arrProto, 'sort', {
        value: customSort,
      });

  }(Array.prototype));
</script>
```

Comment: I'm glad you provided the answer as I was curious about your comment. However, I'm looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: @JimK ... _"I'm glad you provided the answer as I was curious about your comment."_ ... you're welcome. ... _"However, I'm looking for a simpler solution."_ ... in the end it is the only approach which exactly does what the OP did ask for, thus enabling the OP of writing custom comparable types each with its own built in `compare` method  in the most simple way.