# Javascript - An ordered container of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Does Javascript have a container which functions like an ordered set? Is there such a thing which permits duplicate values?

I want to be able to insert objects into a container using something like an `operator<`.

I don't know if it is possible to define an `operator<` as part of a Javascript object.

For example, if the object is:

```
const object = {
    day: 1,
    hour: 22,
    minute: 0
}
```

is it possible to define an `operator<` such that two such objects can be compared and inserted into an ordered container?

Clarification: In programming languages such as C++, `operator<` is a member function (operator) of a class which defines how sorting (ordering) should be.

In C++, one would do something like this:

```
class MyType;

bool operator<(MyType&, MyType &);

std::set<MyType>; // or even std::vector<MyType> v;

// s is ordered (sorted), v is not
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

There are of course other possibilities such as using `make_heap` in combination with `push_heap` and `pop_heap`. But this is approaching the realms of quite specialist knowledge.

Comment: JavaScript does not have definable operators. It has functions. What exactly is `operator<`?

Comment: Also object comparison is completely up to your own code (functions). The native comparison operators compare object references as plain values, so two different objects are never `==` to each other, regardless of their contents.

Comment: If you want an ordered container that allows duplicates, that would just be an array.  You can then design your own insertion function to insert things into the array in the order you desire since you can insert a new item anywhere in the array using `.splice()`.

Comment: If you want an ordered data structure that allows duplicates I'd use a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) or some sort of self-balancing binary search tree.

Comment: @JaredSmith That would be ideal but JS doesn't appear to have any kind of standard implementation for one

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "ordered set that permits duplicates". To me, that sounds less like a set and more like an array. What kind of operations do you want to do and what behaviour and time complexity to you expect from them?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant no JS has no standard library (don't *even* get me started) you'd have to write an implementation or bring in a dependency.

Comment: @Bergi Any container which permits duplicates and can be ordered

Comment: @Bergi It won't have more than 1000 elements or so. Time complexity isn't a critical thing

Comment: Why has this question been closed? How could it possibly be more clear? Does the average Javascript developer not understand what an ordered set or a container is?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Then just use an array, which is the standard go-to container in JavaScript. If that doesn't fit your needs, please explain more specifically what you operations you need or what methods `Array` is lacking. And yes, most JS devs won't know what the terms [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) or [(ordered) set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) mean specifically in C++.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, an array would work fine. The requirements stated in the question were for: a container (of any type) into which an object can be inserted, as defined in the question above, and which can be ordered or sorted in some way defined by the data in the objects. Really, this should not be a difficult question to understand. (That is not intended to be a personal comment directed at yourself, fyi.)

Comment: If you know any C++, this is really a trivial problem. Use a `std::set` and define `operator<` for the type you are intending to insert into the set.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant ... 1/2 ... Late answer/comment ... the OP also could implement own types in a way that they feature e.g a `compareTo` method which allows for more complex comparison than just the coercion into number/string values by custom provided `valueOf`/`toString` methods.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant ... 2/2 ... In order to then sort arrays of such types by just invoking `sort()` without the parameter of a custom compare method, one needs to additionally wrap the native `sort` method as it gets demonstrated by e.g. this answer to ... [_"Comparable custom types which can be sorted as array items without defining an additional compare function inside sort()"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74882525/comparable-custom-types-which-can-be-sorted-as-array-items-without-defining-an-a/74883039#74883039).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define what operators do, but you can define which numerical value an object will represent when it is used as operand. You can define a `valueOf` method on your object (or  have it inherit one).

Little demo:

```js
class Time {
    constructor(day, hour, minute) {
        Object.assign(this, {day, hour, minute});
    }
    valueOf() {  // Will be called implicitly when coercion to number is needed
        return (this.day * 24 + this.hour) * 60 + this.minute;
    }
}

// Example use
const obj1 = new Time(1, 22, 0);
const obj2 = new Time(1, 18, 30);
console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
console.log(obj1 < obj2); // false
console.log(obj1 > obj2); // true
console.log(obj1 - obj2); // 210
```

If the purpose is to use it with *string* comparison, which is the default for the `sort` method, then you could opt to define the `toString` method:

```js
class Time {
    constructor(day, hour, minute) {
        Object.assign(this, {day, hour, minute});
    }
    toString() { // Will be called when coercion to string is needed
        return `${this.day},${this.hour}:${this.minute}`.replace(/\b\d\b/g, "0$&");
    }
}

// Example use
const arr = [new Time(1, 22, 0), new Time(1, 18, 30)];
arr.sort();
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: The function `valueOf` is not being called by the sort function for Array?

Comment: As `sort` uses **string** comparison by default, you can opt to implement the `toString` method in such a way that a lexical order will correspond with the intended order. See addition to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the container is an array, the following will work.

```
// Sort
myArray.sort((a, b) => a - b);

// To see the output
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray, null, 4));
```

This assumes that a function is defined to be able to perform the operation `a - b`. The `valueOf` function will perform coersion to type `Number`.

The full solution I used:

```
class DayAndTime {
    constructor(day, hour, minute, id) {
        Object.assign(this, {day, hour, minute, id});
    }

    valueOf() {
        console.log(`valueOf called`);
        return this.day * 24 * 60 * 60 + this.hour * 60 * 60 + this.minute * 60;
    }
}
```